# move corners of rectangle in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my application I would like to draw a rectangle by joining the points given through mouseclick or touch(which I have done). So I have the array of points(corners) KeyPX[] and KeyPY[]. Now when I finish the shape I should modify the location of the corner. ie when I click again, I should Find/select the nearest corner and move/drag the corner to a new point so that I will get a new shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hit-test if the mouse (touch) is within the `perimeter` of a corner. Think of the perimeter as a circle with its centerpoint == the corner point.

**You can hit-test around the perimeter of a corner like this:**

```
var perimeter = 20; // test if the mouse is within a 20px radius of the corner
var dx = mouseX - cornerX;
var dy = mouseY - cornerY;
var isInside = dx*dx+dy*dy <= perimeter*perimeter
```

Then just erase the canvas and redraw the new shape by stroking through the new vertices using the same coding procedure that you say you already have done.